# Mail attachment from Unix script in loop

Tags: email, attachment

I have below sample script which was working fine until last week, however, not sure what has changed, I am not getting any attachments sent.  I just get greet / text message but not any attachment.  I tried with sample .txt as attachment which is success. But not .csv, not sure if csv's are being filtered by unix server, but I don't see any error message. Any idea how to track / check what is going wrong pls?

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/inbox/*.*
to="test@temp.com"
from="test@temp.com"
subject="Test Files"
filecount=`find $FILES -type f | wc -l`
totalfiles=" : Total "
subject=${subject}${totalfiles}${filecount}
body="Dear All,Please find the attached latest files."
echo $subject $filecount
declare -a attargs
for att in $(find $FILES -type f -name "*.*");do
    #attaching all files.
    attargs+=( "-a" "$att" )
done

mail -s "$subject" -r "$from" "${attargs[@]}" "$to" <<< "$body"**
```

Kind Regards
Kevin

Comment: 1, need quotes around `subject="..."`. 2, `echo $subject $filecount` will be redundant since filecount is already assigned in subject. 3, `FILES=/inbox/*.*` but it's never used anywhere except as a `find` target, so you don't need the `*.*` both in `FILES` *and* the `-name` argument to find. (unless there are files that don't meet the *.* spec, you don't need it at all.) I doubt any of thise will fix your problem, but cleaning up is usually a good place to start.

Comment: thanks you for comments , yes above code was added to check what is going wrong, but didn't actually fixed issue.